# Access Apache Beam metrics values during pipeline run in python?

Tags: python, apache-beam

I'm using the direct runner of Apache Beam Python SDK to execute a simple pipeline similar to the word count example. Since I'm processing a large file, I want to display metrics during the execution. I know how to report the metrics, but I can't find any way to access the metrics during the run.

I found the `metrics()` function in the `PipelineResult`, but it seems I only get a `PipelineResult` object from the `Pipeline.run()` function, which is a blocking call. In the Java SDK I found a `MetricsSink`, which can be configured on `PipelineOptions`, but I did not find an equivalent in the Python SDK.

How can I access live metrics during pipeline execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct runner is generally used for testing, development, and small jobs, and `Pipeline.run()` was made blocking for simplicity. On other runners `Pipeline.run()` is asynchronous and the result can be used to monitor the pipeline progress during execution.

You could try running a local version of an OSS runner like Flink to get this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

As @robertwb mentioned, `DirectRunner` does not support this; but I think If you are running the pipeline locally, even with `FlinkRunner` this is not supported. I was expecting `Pipeline.run()` to be asynchronous but it is not. My pipeline is batch and when I debugged it, it sets `DeploymentOptions.ATTACHED` to `true` [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/2454dfa3aa27006198cd969840b06fe7313b56d0/flink-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/LocalEnvironment.java#L68) which blocks `Pipeline.run()` until the pipeline is done. I am guessing streaming mode does something similar [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/2454dfa3aa27006198cd969840b06fe7313b56d0/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/environment/LocalStreamEnvironment.java#L62) but I have not checked it. There is also [this bug](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/20992).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work with the DirectRunner:

```
counters = result.metrics().query(beam.metrics.MetricsFilter())['counters']
for metric in counters:
    print(metric)
```